# html, что это значит? и как её заменить?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть вот такая запись которая применяется ко всей странице,что тут означает запятая?

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;

}
```

Как простыми div заменить ту верхнею запись и применить её только к элементам ниже то есть обернуть их в классы которые будут давать те свойства сверху только определённым элементам,а не всей странице

```
<div class="space">
  <div class="space__star space__star--shooting"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть HTML-теги... `<html></html>`, `<body></body>`, `<div></div>` и т.п.

Чтобы в CSS обращаться к ним и менять их стили, пишут просто название тега:

```css
body { background-color: #ffe2aa; } 
div { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: orange; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head></head>
<body>
  <div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Если у нескольких элементов должны быть одинаковые стили, их можно перечислять через запятую, чтобы заново не писать одинаковый код.

```
body, div, p, a { color: red; }
```

А название класса можно выделить через точку:

```
.ваш_класс, .другой_класс { у-обоих: те-же-стили; }
```

Перед точкой можно указывать и название тега. Чтобы только эти теги с этим классом получили стиль, `div.класс {...}`

```css
div { 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  border: 2px solid orange;
  margin: 5px; 
}

/* Вообще, принято все стили разбивать на такие блоки - всё на отдельной строчке
Но главный критерий - чтобы удобно было читать код. Если совсем мелкий кусок, 
зачастую удобнее не занимать лишние строки */

.space { background-color: #045acf; }

.space__star { border: none; }
```

```html
<div class="space">
  <div class="space__star space__star--shooting"></div>
</div>

<div></div>
```

[Список CSS - селекторов и их комбинации >>](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: Можете подсказать вот код я где хотел убрать из css html,body как тут их заменить на div с определённым id https://codepen.io/Alexander3232/pen/gNPwjW

Comment: Пытался сделать обёртку но не срабатывало

Comment: Этот кусок вообще можно убрать из кода ( именно CSS, а не HTML ). А блоку `space` дописать стили `.space { width: 200px; height: 100px }` - и всё...

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый и подробный ответ дал лучшего